# Devexpress, cambiar posicion popup

Tags: devexpress, popup

Tengo un pop un pop up, al que le quiero cambiar la posición en la que aparece al pulsar para que se abra.

He probado varias cosas, y no se si es posible posicionarlo donde quiera de la pantalla.

Estoy usando la versión mas reciente de devexpress

Y el código que uso es muy básico

```
<dxe:MemoEdit 
     PopupFooterButtons="None"
     ShowEditorButtons="False"
     ShowSizeGrip="False"
     Name="nombe" 
     PopupOpened="PopupNAme_PopupOpened">                                
</dxe:MemoEdit>
```

Comment: Esto es aspx.net? dbería ser el control ASPxMemo? Disculpa, pero me he deshubicado con tu pregunta y eso que utilizo los controles de Devexpress cada día

Comment: Es WPF. Ya esta, acabo de publicar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, la dejo por aquí por si os sirve.

Mi vista, con mis configuraciones, cada uno tendrá las que necesite.

```
<dxe:MemoEdit
      PopupFooterButtons="None"
      ShowEditorButtons="False"
      ShowSizeGrip="False"
      AcceptsReturn="True"
      AcceptsTab="True"
      MemoVerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
      PopupHeight="150"
      Name="name">                                
</dxe:MemoEdit>
```

Y en el .cs de la ventana. Podéis poner este metodo en el evento que necesitéis del memo

```
private void OpenCustomMemoEdit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var memo = (MemoEdit)sender;
            var popup = memo.GetPopup();

            popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Left;
            popup.VerticalOffset = memo.ActualHeight;
            popup.HorizontalOffset = -5;
            popup.MinWidth = this.PopupMemoDescripcion.ActualWidth;
        }
```

Como veis en el objeto popup tenéis todo lo que necesitáis para posicionar el desplable del pop up como necesitéis.